# How can I add a global control matcher in Storybook?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, storybook

I am building a component library in React and TypeScript using Storybook. Many components have an icon prop. In the code snippet below, you can see a Component story example where I customize the icon prop's control using a select type with icon options.

```
// Component.stories.js

import { Component } from './component';
import { iconOptions, DefaultIcon } from "./icons";

export default {
  component: Component,
  title: 'Component',
  argTypes: {
    icon: {
      control: {
        type: 'select'
      },
      options: iconOptions,
      defaultValue: DefaultIcon
    }
  }
};
```

The problem is that this setup is repetitive for all components using icon prop. Instead, I would like to configure this globally for all components. So any prop called `icon` would automatically get a `select` control with icon options.

I tried editing the `.storybook/preview.js` file:

```
export const parameters = {
    controls: {
        icon: {
            control: {
                type: 'select'
            },
            options: iconOptions,
            defaultValue: DefaultIcon,
        }
    }
};
```

However, that did not work.

How can I configure such a global control?

Comment: Can't you just assign the section of your of code to a variable and import it?  And then use `argTypes: { icon }` wherever needed.

Comment: While that could be an option, it doesn’t solve the problem especially when you have multiple of these props. For example, color, backgroundColor accepting a custom enum from a color palette (not any hex from color picker), theme or any other prop that is commonly used in other components.

Comment: I think that this question is in line with an open "feature request" in the storybook github repo. I am currently unable to find the issue link. I will share it if I find it. (this seems to be a good feature)

Comment: Found it. [Addon-controls: configuring argTypes globally on preview.js](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/11697). It is not exactly what you are looking for in this question. But I think It is similar.

Comment: Can you post an example as an answer? I can't seem to get it working.